# Submitting app - Add Localizations, but my language is not listed in the combo box?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I am about to submit my app. I have followed the upload guide, and I selected English as primary language since Norwegian is not listed, because it ensured me that you can add localizations afterwards. I did, even though my app only will be sold in Norway. Now I clicked add localizations, but still, no norwegian in the combobox. What should I do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same story in Czech Republic. Treat it formally as an English application. You can fill Description and What's new in Norwegian and put English translation into Review Notes. Optionally, you can add English description just after Norwegian. Accidental non-Norwegian users will appreciate it.